# How the function do_raw_spin_lock is implemented in linux

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linux-kernel, spinlock

While debugging panic issue realted to spinlock, I came across this definition of spinlock in

> include/linux/spinlock.h

. It is rather hard for me to understand this definition. Why is `__acquires(lock)` used after the `do_raw_spin_lock` function? What is the signification of such declaration?

```
static inline void do_raw_spin_lock(raw_spinlock_t *lock) __acquires(lock)
{
        __acquire(lock);
        arch_spin_lock(&lock->raw_lock);
}
```

Please help me how such declaration are decoded and work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used for static analysis.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse